# How to send parameter by thymleaf?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a controller say,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/{lastname}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String searchAlpha(@PathVariable String lastname) {
        log.info("-------------------");
        log.info(lastname);
        return "welcome";
    }
```

And a form

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/search/__${lastName}__}" method="get" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class = "form-group">
            <input th:field="*{lastName}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
              </span>
        </div>
```

How do make send as parameter without using model?

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to do it.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/search}" method="get" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class = "form-group">
            <input name="lastname" id="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
              </span>
        </div>
</form>
```

And in the controller instead of @pathvariable make it @Requestparam

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String searchAlpha(@RequestParam String lastname) {
        log.info(lastname);
        return "welcome";
    }
```